# Simperium with a document base Core Data app

Tags: simperium

Is it possible to use Simperium (http://simperium.com) with a document based Core Data app? The sample is a "Shoebox" style app and I don't see any option to set a document id or something.

If not, would it be possible to extend Simperium with such an option?

The service really looks great! Would love to see if it's as a good replacement for iCloud as it seems (accessing the data from a backend is a very good feature!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document-based Core Data apps aren't supported yet, but we'll consider that a good feature request. Thanks, and happy you think it's great!

Comment: I shall ask each day: "is it finished yet?" ;)

Comment: Thanks for your instant answer!

Comment: Just a quick update: got a response from the Simperium team that supporting Document-based Core Data apps is not on the roadmap currently.